# Serializing an Object into BLOB column of a derby database writes more Bytes than expected

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to (de)serialize a SortedMap into a derby database table. The Map

```
private static Map<String, String> categories;
```

is serialized when the application terminates and deserialized on next start. I use the following for deserializing it from a recordset 'rs':

```
byte[] b = rs.getBytes(1);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
setCategories((SortedMap<String, String>) ois.readObject());
```

where setCategories() wraps the Map as:

```
this.categories = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(map);
```

and this to serialize it with a PreparedStatement:

```
ObjectOutputStream oop = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oop.writeObject(this.categories);
byte[] b = os.toByteArray();
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
pst.setBinaryStream(2, is, b.length);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

The code (regarding this issue slightly simplified) compiles and runs fine, but outputting the corresponding lengths of the byte arrays when doing nothing than reading and writing the Map shows, that each time the map is serialized, more Bytes are written than had been read, so the size of it is growing (by 17 bytes to be specific)...? I don't want to end up with a Map containing a few Strings that needs 2GB of diskspace and that...

The data type of the column i want to (de)serialize the map (from)to is BLOB. 
All resources are closed after finishing, at least as far as i'm concerned.

Any ideas? Your help is kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you read the map, you wrap it into a new SynchronizedSortedMap "wrapper" and then you write that wrapper into the database. This way, the next time you read it, you get a SynchronizedSortedMap and wrap it with one more SynchronizedSortedMap, essentially layering an additional wrapper every time you read and write.

The easiest solution is to ensure you write a SynchronizedSortedMap the very first time, and then not wrap it further when you read it from the database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me - I had'nt been aware of that till now. I'm using `SortedMap` as declaring type of the relevant fields in my classes and it works fine now. Thanks again.